# How to SELECT FROM WHERE in excel? Return rows from database

Tags: excel, select, excel-formula, row, where-clause

I want to return rows from a table, where certain conditions are met, in excel.

```
ProdGroup   Width (mm)  Diameter (mm)   Date
Prod1           1120            1000   2016-01-11
Prod2           600             1000   2017-10-18
Prod1           930             800    2015-04-11
Prod3           1250            1200   2016-04-18
Prod2           840             1000   2019-06-27
Prod2           840              900   2018-03-21
```

I want to be make an equivalent of:  "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ProdGroup = "Prod2" AND Diameter = 1000"
in excel. My idea is that I enter the values into two cells and that rows are returned based on what I write in the two cells.

I have tried using the =INDEX() function but I only managed to search for rows matching only 1 condition. Furthermore, I only succeeded return one row.

```
=INDEX(B2:D6,MATCH(A10,A2:A6,0),1)
```

This only gives me one IN parameter. With Prod2 this would only return one row.

With inputs "Prod2" and 1000:

```
ProdGroup         Diameter
Prod2             1000
```

I want an outcome like this:

```
Prod2           600             1000            2017-12-18
Prod2           840             1000            2019-06-27
```

I have no idea on how to go about doing this. Can somebody please help?

Kind regards
pbdude

Comment: use advanced filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option:

[image]

Formula in `I2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$7,SMALL(IF((($A$2:$A$7=$F$2)*($C$2:$C$7=$G$2))>0,ROW($A$2:$A$7),""),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down and right...

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an automated example, you can use a macro. This will prevent you from having to drag a formula down and increases the integrity of your data as it reduces the likelihood for errors and eliminates the chances of a formula not encompassing the entire range of data cells, or being typed over.

In case you are unfamiliar with VBA...

- Save your workbook as a .xlsm file (macro enabled workbook)
- Press alt + F11 to open the VBE window
- Right-Click on your file name in the project explorer on the left side of the screen
- Choose Insert > Module
- In the newly created module, paste this code below.
- You can run the macro by going to Developer > Macros or from there choose Options and assign the keyboard shortcut of your choice.

To customize this for your specific data, you only need to replace the text inside the quotation marks with your specific table name and named ranges, in the Set Variables section.

In the example below, I used named ranges for the cells that will be used as the filter parameters.  I also formatted the data to be filtered as a table.  The table name is t_ProductSizes.

This snip shows the filtered result and the named range of the active cell.

[image]

```
Sub FilterTable_ByCellReference()

'~~> Declare the variables
Dim t As ListObject
Dim p As String
Dim w As String
Dim dm As String
Dim dt As String

'~~> Set the variables
'~~> Replace the text inside the quotation marks with your table names and named ranges.

Set t = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("t_ProductSizes")
p = Range("filter_product") 'named range
w = Range("filter_width") 'named range
dm = Range("filter_diameter") 'named range
dt = Range("filter_date") 'named range

'~~> Check your variables if you like (view the immediate window)
Debug.Print "t = " & t.Name
Debug.Print "p = " & p
Debug.Print "w = " & w
Debug.Print "dm = " & dm
Debug.Print "dt = " & dt

'~~> Remove existing filters.
    t.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1

'~~> Filter the table based on the values specified in the filter cells.
'~~> Only filter the corresponding column if the cell is not blank.

    With t.Range

        If p <> "" Then

            .AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:=p

        End If

        If w <> "" Then

            .AutoFilter Field:=2, _
                Criteria1:=w

        End If

        If dm <> "" Then

            .AutoFilter Field:=3, _
                Criteria1:=dm

        End If

        If dt <> "" Then

            .AutoFilter Field:=4, _
                Criteria1:=DateValue(dt)

        End If

    End With


'~~> Clear the variables from memory.
Set t = Nothing
p = vbNullString
w = vbNullString
dm = vbNullString
dt = vbNullString

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Jenn! Thank you so much for some answer. As someone who is completely new to VB, I greatly appreciate your thorough explanation. I'm having some trouble applying your macro and would be very grateful if you could tell me what I am doing wrong.

I keep getting this error message when trying to use your macro:
"Run-time error '9'. Subscript out of range"

I did not change the code and changed the name of cells and tables so they fit the code. 

This is how I defined the names: 
https://imgur.com/a/2D6l8Lz

What did I do wrong? :))

KR
pbdude

Comment: @pbdude You are very welcome. I can take a look this evening and reply again.

Comment: @pbdude Script out of range usually means whatever you referenced doesnt exist. Can you check the spelling for your table name and named ranges?

Comment: Ok great! I really appreciate it. I checked the spelling and it is spelt the same way as you wrote it in the code.